# String manipulation to truncate string up to a specified expression on C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

How do I remove more than three spaces from each line and end the string right there to look the line on the right using c#?

```
[Example1]  
PO BOX XXX                                       OVERDUE - PAY NOW  
then transform to  
PO BOX XXX

[Example2]  
ClientB                                AMOUNT CARRI  
then transform to  
ClientB  

[Example3]  
PO BOX 400                                                    FORWARD TO N  
then transform to  
PO BOX 400
```

Comment: You need to explain the criterias of truncation better. Currently your description doesn't fit your examples.

Comment: Sorry the text editor removed all the spaces. Here is what I am trying to do: [link]http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/833/unledrrx.png/

Comment: @Arun Not necessarily three spaces but like above a lot of spaces. Sometimes it is possible to have 2 spaces between client names because of Typing error so I wanted to be cautious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var firstColumn = origString.SubString(0, origString.IndexOf("   "));
```

Comment: My string actually has variable spaces in between. It is a CSV file but when I do IndexOf("   ") it does not return anything.  [link]http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/811/unledssu.png/

Answer (score 4):

```
input = "PO BOX XXX                                       OVERDUE - PAY NOW  ";
input = input.Remove(input.IndexOf("   "));
```

there are 3 spaces in the indexOf paranthesis

Or you can do a split if you dont know if there is a tab or space -

```
input = input.Split(new char[] {' ', '\t'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];
```

Comment: as I mentioned above, I was wrong to think that three spaces will solve the problem. Do you know how I can transform like this (link below)  [link]http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/811/unledssu.png/

Comment: Look at the edit - so if you dont know what kind of space is there - tab or space, then that would work.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
var input = new string[3] { "PO BOX XXX                                       OVERDUE - PAY NOW  ", 
                                      "ClientB                                AMOUNT CARRI",
                                      "PO BOX 400                                                    FORWARD TO N  "
                                    };

    for (int x = 0, len = input.Length; x != len; x++)
    {
         input[x] = Regex.Replace(input[x], @"\s{3}[^\n]+", string.Empty);
    }
     //input is ["PO BOX XXX","ClientB","PO BOX 400"]
```

**Using linq:**

```
 var output = input.Select(str => Regex.Replace(str, @"\s{3}[^\r\n]+$", string.Empty));
```

if you're reading this string from file, you can do this:

```
var file = @"D:\file.txt";
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
var output = lines.Select(str => Regex.Replace(str, @"\s{3}[^\n]+$", string.Empty)); // is ["PO BOX XXX","ClientB","PO BOX 400"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the string.Split method which results the string[]. Basing on the array count you can take the elements u need.

```
string base string = "PO BOX XXX OVERDUE - PAY NOW";
string[] delimittedStringArray = baseString.Split(' ');
if(delimittedStringArray.Length > 3)
{
  // Take the data from array
}
else
{
  // Do what ever
}
```

// I am not sure whether it is Length or Count in the if condition.